# how to give access to a user in one AWS account to AWS datapipeline in another account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-data-pipeline

I have two aws accounts. I have a user in account a which needs to have full access to aws data pipeline in account B. 
How to achieve this?

I have attached a policy to the user in account A to have access to data pipeline.

But how do I attach a policy to datapipeline in account B so that it accepts requests from this user from account A?

Answer (score 0):

AWS STS with Assume Role will let you setup with cross account resource access. There is a very descriptive [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=crV99Di9EUs) by AWS to help understand & setup the same. For your case, instead of EC2 you will just give Datapipeline access.